# Get common values within multiple groupby in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas dataframe and I would like to find common values of 'col2' within multiple groups grouped by 'col1'

```
 col1    col2
  a       abc
          pqr
          xyz

  b       abc      
          def
          bcd

  c       bcd
          efg
```

The output should be as follows:

```
     abc      [a,b]
     bcd      [b,c]
```

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace('',np.nan).ffill()

s = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(list)
s = s[s.str.len() > 1].reset_index()
print (s)
  col2    col1
0  abc  [a, b]
1  bcd  [b, c]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) empty values to `NaN`s and forward fill `NaN`s
2. For each value of `col2` aggregate `list`s
3. Filter lists by lengths by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)